# Elegantly switching branch with uncommitted changes

Tags: git-checkout

When working with multiple feature branches in parallel, I need to `stash` or `commit` the local changes before I can switch to another branch. I think both stash and commit feel rather clumsy to me. Is there a more elegant alternative?

Why `stash` is clumsy: I work on multiple branches and switch between them from time to time. Sometimes I end up forgetting to pop, or popping the wrong stash.

Why `commit` is clumsy: my changes are work-in-progress. They are not complete and should not be committed. What I end up doing is committing them first (because I'm forced to), and later doing a soft reset so that my previous commit comes back to "local changes". Or, sometimes I let the temporary commits pile up and do an interactive rebase later.

What I'm looking for: like a "smart stash". Stash the local changes automatically when I switch to a another branch, and pop the stash associated with this branch automatically when I switch back. Could this be done?

Comment: I doubt any Git provider supports your requirement, Stash is the only option here

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to create a temporary commit for work in progress, and for each noncommittal save of work status before switching branch, always use `git commit --amend`. The `--amend` flag lets you create a commit that *replaces* the current-branch-pointed commit (in our case, an unserious, work-in-progress commit), rather than create additional commits on top of it. Each time you commit with `--amend`, your commit message could actually be "NO COMMIT" to remind yourself of that. Then you can forget about all the complications of Git, and just think of `commit --amend` like the good old SAVE button that lets you overwrite your previous file (the non-serious commit) again and again, leaving no additional traces.

When you've worked enough and decide this unserious, status-saving commit should become a real commit, then just `git commit` without `--amend`, then on top of that, create the next unserious commit with the message "NO COMMIT"

I guess this is the easiest way to save work-in-progress for people who have to jump between different branches often.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use [`git worktree`, which allows you to have *multiple* working directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)

That way, switching branches can mean simply leaving your current work in progress as is, and.. changing folder.
No need to automatically stash/commit.

The drawbacks of that approach could be:

- disk space (if your project is really *huge*)
- tool configuration (your IDE needs to load the same project from different paths, which is generally possible through IDE workspace)